# Regex: How many strings start with letters and end with numbers?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a Regex expression that searches through a text file with a bunch of names, phone numbers, emails, and garbage, to find **how many strings start with letters and end with numbers?**  Line by line searching.

Any help?  I know it needs to start like this I believe.  Thanks.

/^[a-z]

Here is a test using the code provided by one of you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTrM3.png

Comment: What do you mean by "how many strings"? Do you want to analyze it word by word? Line by line? All possible substrings of the file's contents?

Comment: Line by line.  Thank you need to clarify!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Show some sample input/output

Comment: How you count things and how you go line by line through a file depends on the language.  Also by letter do you mean ASCII only or all Unicode letters?  Same for digits.... 0..9 or all Unicode digits?

Comment: The count of matches would depend on language, so please specify language

Comment: You've gotto give sample Input and Output. And also, some effort..

Comment: I was just using the Unix command line.  Here is a screenshot using the guy below me's code.  http://i.imgur.com/fryS50J.png

Answer (score 5):

^[A-Za-z]+.*[0-9]+$

here the explanation:
^ .. at the start of a paragraph

[A-Za-z]+ .. any letter occurs at least once, then

.* .. any character except line break or paragraph break occurs 0 to n times

[0-9]+ .. there is at least one number

$ ..  at the end of a paragraph

You can use a online regex testing tool to check if your regex is correct:
http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

And here is a list of regex expressions:
https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions

Answer (score -2):

The regex for a word that start with letters and ends with numbers is:

```
[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+
```

Comment: " start with letters and end with numbers" --> abc-100-123-200 will not be matched. I guess the Op wants this matched.

Comment: Actually, no.  You don't capture things like A3V2.  Nor are you checking word boundaries.  Nor characters that are neither letters nor digits....